What happens to light that never hits anything?
Im a blue collar worker, just had a thought. What would happen to photons that never hit anything. It must be possible that at least one photon out there somewhere just happened to not ever hit anything. Would it ever change states? Does it become dark matter? I googled a bunch and checked on here i couldnt find a similar question.

If it does not interact with anything, then it will stay itself and keep moving forward. It is, however, possible to bend a ray of light.

The main problem with the question is that "photons" are not atomistic constituents of light. They are the amounts of energy that the electromagnetic field exchanges with systems that emit and absorb radiation. In essence there are no photons unless light is being emitted or absorbed somewhere.

@FlatterMan photon exist as they propagate, even before they are detected. How do you think they got there. I understand that they are not perceived as light until something can detect them but that doesn't mean they're not there. Many things fall into that type of situation. If someone throws a rock at you and you don't see or know its coming until it hits your head, you can't say it didn't exist until you absorbed it, I mean felt it.

Since the universe is expanding everywhere,  you don't have to worry about the photon hitting the "Edge" , as evidenced by galaxies that are moving [expanding] away from Earth so fast that their light will never reach us.

@BillAlsept You are welcome to tell us which experiment demonstrates propagating photons. I have never seen one. I do, of course, understand that the classically trained human mind wants to interpolate things at all cost. In quantum mechanics the cost of that interpolation is a logical error.

@CarlWitthoft You actually do have to worry about photons that will never be detected. They are breaking energy, momentum and angular momentum conservation for the local observer. Since one can not catch a light wave all energy that is not contained in a perfectly isolating "Schroedinger cat box" leads to decoherence. That is what is really behind the quantum mechanical measurement/observation riddle... it's all the energy that gets away from us and that we can't say anything about because we can't measure it any longer.

So would that be the answer then?  It is immeasurable?

@FlatterMan, now you're just being silly or stubborn. Of course, photons propagate, but according to your logic, nothing exists if it can't be seen. You're welcome to tell us which experiment directly demonstrates an electromagnetic field or a light wave. Why would you not believe in electrons, quarks, or neutrinos if you can't see them propagate either?

@BillAlsept Energy flows, but that's not enough to make it "a photon". Of course I can't demonstrate an electromagnetic field at the microscopic level. It does not exist and I never claimed that it does. The only thing that exists at this level are irreversible energy, momentum, angular momentum and charge exchanges that we call "quanta". Those we can demonstrate but they always require an emitting or absorbing system in addition to the free field. This isn't hard to understand, especially once you had to write a purchase order for a $20k Hamamatsu PMT. No PMT, no photons.

@FlatterMann, earlier you mentioned electromagnetic fields, implying that you believe in their existence. Using your own terminology, how do you demonstrate the flow of energy, the exchange of charge, or the concept of quanta? Furthermore, how can you prove that something is emitted? According to your logic and sequence of operations, nothing (whether photons, quanta, energy, fields, waves, light, radio waves, or even sound) can ever be considered emitted if it hasn't been detected. Sound like the old saying "If a tree falls in the woods....."

@BillAlsept You are correct. I should have called it "the quantized electromagnetic field". I mistakenly assumed that that was clear from the context. How do I demonstrate all of these quantized energy and charge flows? With experimental hardware like PMTs and Millikan experiments. The latter is one of the most fascinating tabletop experiments I have ever done. To experience that one can catch a single electron in an oil droplet and then make it hover in mid air is just very cool. We should introduce it in high school. I know of very few physics experiments that bring reality home this nicely.

The Cosmic Microwave Background is light that was emitted at the beginning of the universe, shortly after the Big Bang.
It has been traveling ever since. That was 13.7 billion years ago. The light is now far older than the earth, which is about 4.5 billion years old.
As it traveled, the universe expanded. This slowly stretched the wavelength of this light. Visible light became redder, then infrared, and eventually microwaves.
Today, those waves can be detected as some of them hit the Earth. We have learned a lot about the early universe from them.

Light usually travels in a straight line. However, gravity can bend light. This was one of the first things Einstein discovered when he thought about the implications of General Relativity. He predicted that if light from a distant star happened to pass very close to the Sun, it would be deflected about $1/1000^{th}$ of a degree. This turned out to be right.
Sometimes light from a really distant galaxy passes by another galaxy or a group of galaxies on its way to Earth. These are large enough to bend light significantly. Their gravity can focus light, like a giant lens. This is called Gravitational Lensing. Sometimes it magnifies the distant galaxy. Sometimes it distorts the image of the distant galaxy. It allows us to see a few galaxies that would otherwise be too faint for even the largest telescopes.

So as it moves (exists) its wavelengths change, so if it became as you said microwaves. Then what happens after that. It would only makes sense that it would continue to change or else reach a point where it starts to go into a different (possibly negative)  state.

The wavelength is continuing to grow.

It cant grow infinitely. Nothing does

Other wise my gf would be satisfied

@SeanBrittain Wavelength is proportional to one over energy and energy can go to zero, hence wavelength can actually go to infinity.
